# Can you modify a python file with a .exe file?

Tags: python, macos, authentication

**TL,DR: Can you use a .exe file to modify a .py file, specifically, a variable in a .py file?** I intend to use this on a mac. I'm trying to make a python file to check to see if there are too many password login attempts being made on my High Sierra mac, and if so when the password is correctly guessed, shut down the computer and alert me. I got everything else to work, but the python script to email me the alert requires a variable to be changed.

Comment: Sure you can modify a Python file with an `.exe` file. Is that really what you wanted to know? Please read [ask].

Comment: Also, why are you trying to modify your script with another program? That seems like a mistake. Maybe tell us more about why you think you need that, and we can help with the _real_ problem. This is very likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: A python file is just text. Anything that modifies text can modify a python program.

Comment: You right. I'm an idiot. I just realized I can have the .exe file open the python file and forego the variable altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you can make a python file become a `.exe`, you can have a `.exe` edit another python file.